# installing OpenSSL in ubuntu fails on building

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am having this error when I `cargo run --bin asscociate` to start my project:

```
install ./include/openssl/aes.h -> /media/adeel/New Volume/company/project/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-422f5ac101ee2531/out/openssl-build/install/include/openssl/aes.h

--- stderr
cp: target 'Volume/company/project/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-422f5ac101ee2531/out/openssl-build/install/include/openssl/aes.h' is not a directory
make: *** [Makefile:2302: install_dev] Error 1
  thread 'main' panicked at '


  Error installing OpenSSL:
      Command: cd "/media/adeel/New Volume/company/project/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-422f5ac101ee2531/out/openssl-build/build/src" && "make" "install_dev"
      Exit status: exit status: 2


      ', /home/adeel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-src-300.1.5+3.1.3/src/lib.rs:577:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I have tried all the methods but still failed I have everything installed still I am facing this error I dont know why I have tried each and every solution from the internet.

```
Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.93
    Building [=======================> ] 395/409: openssl-sys(build)
```

It stops here and shows the above error.

Comment: This looks like a bug with properly quoting file names somewhere. As a workaround, you could try with a directory name that does not include space characters, e.g. `new-volume` instead of `New Volume`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yes i got the same answer on discord server thanks it helped

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs. Currently the question is harder to read.

Comment: `make` generally doesn't deal well with paths with spaces. Also, if openssl makes too much trouble, many crates allow using `rustls` instead, like [reqwest](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/#optional-features) for example.